# Where are Windows 10 audio input device settings stored?

Tags: windows, audio, windows-10

I am developing an application that needs to programmatically DISABLE exclusive mode for a microphone so that it can always record. Apparently that setting is not stored in the registry, since I exported the registry before and after changing the setting, and the files were identical. Does anyone know where that setting is stored?

Specifically, I am speaking of the setting found thus:

- right click the speaker icon in the task notification area
- click Recording devices
- click the device of interest
- click Properties
- click Advanced
- uncheck Allow applications to take exclusive control ...
- click Apply
- click OK

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This is from Windows 7, not 10. But I imagine these settings did not change.

In the Local Machine hive, you'll need to go to this subkey: `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture`

This will provide you with a list of subkeys that are GUIDs, one for each capture device on the machine. Each of those subkeys has a Properties subkey. That exposes the various settings for each microphone. The allow exclusive audio mode key is `{b3f8fa53-0004-438e-9003-51a46e139bfc},3`. It will need to be set to `0`.

The problem you will run into is that these Capture device are owned by the `SYSTEM` user in the registry, and thus are difficult to modify as an executable/script run the by the user.

The proper way to do this is to use the MMDevice API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316556(v=vs.85).aspx). You can ask the API for all audio devices of a specific type, then iterate through them and find the one you want. You can then get properties for that device and simply change the value using the SetValue method. This automatically updates the registry.